# Is this spaghetti code already?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I post the following code writen all by hand. Why I have the feeling that it is a western spaghetti on its own. Second, could that be written better?

```
    <div id="form-board" class="notice" style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;display: none;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".form-button-slide").click(function(){
                $( "#form-board" ).dialog();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('mysubmit');
    echo $this->Form->input('inputs', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'inputs', 'options' => $inputs));
    echo $this->Form->input('Fields', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'fields', 'empty' => '-- Pick a state first --'));

    echo $this->Form->input('inputs2', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'inputs2', 'options' => $inputs2));
    echo $this->Form->input('Fields2', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'fields2', 'empty' => '-- Pick a state first --'));

    echo $this->Form->end("Submit");
    ?>
</div>
<div style="width:100%"></div>
<div class="form-button-slide" style="float:left;display:block;">
    <?php echo $this->Html->link("Error Results", "#"); ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mysubmitIndexForm").submit(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            jQuery.post("Staffs/view", { data1: $("#inputs").attr('value'), data2:$("#inputs2").attr('value'),data3:$("#fields").attr('value'), data4:$("#fields2").attr('value') }            );
            //Close the dialog
            $( "#form-board" ).dialog('close')
            return false;
        });

        $("#inputs").change(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var input_id     = $('#inputs').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //The controller who listens to our request
                url: "Inputs/getFieldsFromOneInput/"+input_id,
                data: "input_id="+ input_id, //+"&amp; lname="+ lname,
                success: function(data){//function on success with returned data
                    $('form#mysubmit').hide(function(){});
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    var sel = $("#fields");
                    sel.empty();
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
        $("#inputs2").change(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var input_id     = $('#inputs2').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //The controller who listens to our request
                url: "Inputs/getFieldsFromOneInput/"+input_id,
                data: "input_id="+ input_id, //+"&amp; lname="+ lname,
                success: function(data){//function on success with returned data
                    $('form#mysubmit').hide(function(){});
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    var sel = $("#fields2");
                    sel.empty();
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yannis did a good job with his review +1 to him. This is just an addition. I think there should be better form names and ID's than inputs, inputs2, etc... These are meaningless. If you can define their purpose then should be able to attribute a better name for them. Such as username or something more descriptive. This helps you identify it later and helps other programmers who might take over your work in the future. With that being said, a better way than incrementing an integer onto the end of your fields is to use array syntax (`inputs[]`).

Comment: off course, you are right about the indices. I build up this, by looking some tutorial in order to somehow build a responsive ui with combo boxes in parent-child relationship.so simple!I only needed fast to see results. One side.The other is that because I don't know Jq/ajax, really took me quite a lot and really I am disappointed on one side, and on the other, I didn't know. really. I mean to find how to pass 4 variables from jquery to php back to the controller, I could never imagine that I had to 'post' when in php keyword 'return' is sufficient&clear.after 3 hours I was really...

Comment: @showerhead I was going to mention the naming, however I took a quick look at my IDE (open at my 2nd monitor at the time), was reminded of how bad I am at naming things and decided to not say a thing ;) To get an idea, I have a function called `voodoo()`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Move all your Javascript out of the way.**

From [Yahoo's Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html):

> **Make JavaScript and CSS External**
>
> Many of these performance rules deal with how external components are managed. However, before these considerations arise you should ask a more basic question: Should JavaScript and CSS be contained in external files, or inlined in the page itself?
>
> Using external files in the real world generally produces faster pages because the JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser. JavaScript and CSS that are inlined in HTML documents get downloaded every time the HTML document is requested. This reduces the number of HTTP requests that are needed, but increases the size of the HTML document. On the other hand, if the JavaScript and CSS are in external files cached by the browser, the size of the HTML document is reduced without increasing the number of HTTP requests.

Obviously, what's more important right now is to minimize that glorious readability mess, hopefully the (small) performance gain might be just the incentive you needed.

**Cache your jQuery objects**

You are using `$('#inputs')` in `$("#mysubmitIndexForm").submit( ... );` and twice in `$("#inputs").change( ... );`. That's three times jQuery traverses the DOM to find `#inputs`, what you need to do is:

```
var inputs = $("#inputs");
```

at the top of your (external) script, and then use `$(inputs)` instead. Do it for all your objects, even if you're using them once, it will stay with you as a (good) habit.

**Avoid inline CSS**

Consider moving all your style declarations into an external CSS file. Other than a slight performance gain (similar to external JavaScript), you'll have all your style declarations in one, easy to find, place.

---

If you do all of the above, your code would look like:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myFunkyScript.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myFunkyStyles.css" />
</head>

    ...
        
    <div id="form-board" class="notice>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('mysubmit');
        echo $this->Form->input('inputs', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'inputs', 'options' => $inputs));
        echo $this->Form->input('Fields', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'fields', 'empty' => '-- Pick a state first --'));

        echo $this->Form->input('inputs2', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'inputs2', 'options' => $inputs2));
        echo $this->Form->input('Fields2', array('type' => 'select', 'id' => 'fields2', 'empty' => '-- Pick a state first --'));

        echo $this->Form->end("Submit");
        ?>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="form-button-slide">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link("Error Results", "#"); ?>
    </div>
```

and what's up with that empty `<div></div>`? If you just want to add some `margin-bottom`, why not do that on `.notice` instead?

Comment: Yannis, thank you a lot for your time and effort to provide me all this explanation. Quite awesome. If I mention that this code you saw, was originally started from some tutorial on the net [and while I do not know JQuery or Ajax fundamentally] it took me perhaps 4 hours maximum, including searching tutorials, screens, help etc etc. [One side effect I had was that I could not understand how to send from JQuery to php back, plain data. And some efforts I tried were useless, like .serialize() totally zero!], how would you comment then? Lost time?

Comment: @hephestos Lost time? Not at all. It works, and that's what's important, that's what you should go for at first. After you get it to work as expected, phase two is to make it look good. In time, both phases will blend, and writing readable code will become instinctual. Now, teresko has a [great point](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12748/4673) about the prominence of `$this`, rewrite your code to move JS and CSS out of the way, and then post a new question here with your full PHP code, there seems to be room for improvement there as well.

Comment: actually , if you would follow Yahoo guidelines , the JavaScript would be included at the bottom

Comment: @teresko Depends on the script, really.

Comment: @YannisRizos , true , there are exceptions. But that's only in very specific cases. But even then they are **not used** inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: Is there a notable difference when declaring `var inputs = $("#inputs");` from later using `$(inputs).someJqueryFunction()` to `inputs.someJqueryFunction()`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can. Here are few things:

- CSS should be in a separate file
- JavaScript should be in a separate file
- JS file should be included at the bottom, before `</body>`. At that point all the content of file would already be "inside" an `onDomReady` "event".

Also prominence of `$this` in the code makes me think, that this is inside some class definition.

Comment: Note on `$this` - looks like a cakephp view template, the `$this` is used to invoke helpers to create html.